# I need help i keep geting this unity error? Assets\ScoreTextScript.cs(10,10): error CS0426: The type name 'Text' does not exist in the type 'Text'

Tags: visual-studio

So this is my code. Im trying to make it so the coins collected add to the score in the UI.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class ScoreTextScript : MonoBehaviour
{

Text.Text
   coinAmount;


//Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    text = GetComponent<Text>();
}

//Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    text.Text = coinAmount;
}
}
```

The **Text** is the error but I don't know how to fix it.
I need help immediately

Answer (score 0):

*I think you don't understand how variables work in unity.*

First you are declaring a Text.text called **coinAmount**

1. In Unity **when** you are **declaring a variable** you **first** have to set the **access modifier**.

The 2 main are: **private and public.**

- **private means** your variable will **only** be **accessible** **in the class you declared it**.
- **public means** you can **access** it from **any other class** if you make a reference to that script.

2. **Then** you need to put the **type** of your variable.
   Here you used Text.text and that's not a type for a variable.

You can set to *int, string, etc...* If you want to use a Text component in unity do like this:

```
private Text coinAmount;
```

Since it's a **private** variable you **can't drag** it **in the editor**. If you want to be able to place a Text component by hand in the editor you can either do:

```
public Text coinAmount;
//or
[SerializeField] private Text coinAmount; //I'll let you search about SerializeField
```

In your Start method you are assigning text variable to the **Text** component this object hold. But **text** does not exist. If you **declare** a **variable** in a **method** it will **only** be **accessible** **in this method.**

So, what you want is:

```
private void Start(){
    coinAmount = GetComponent<Text>();
}
```

And lastly i see you want to assign your text to the variable we created earlier. *That's useless.* You need to create a new variable of type int and assign it to the **text** value of **coinAmount**.

To do so:

We will create a **new variable** right under coinAmount.

```
public int coinNumber;
```

And in update we can use it:

```
private void Update(){
    coinAmount.text = coinNumber.ToString(); //.ToString() is used when you want to convert something to a string (which is a type of variable).
}
```

And there we go everything should work correctly !

The whole code:

```
private Text coinAmount;
public int coinNumber;

private void Start(){
    coinAmount = GetComponent<Text>();
}


private void Update(){
    coinAmount.text = coinNumber.ToString(); //.ToString() is used when you want to convert something to a string (which is a type of variable).
}
```

Hope it helped ! Have a nice day !